# SQL fill field from two existing in table

Tags: sql, select

I want to select, 3 field into my table: first and second are `bool`. Third is `(fist = 0 && second = 0)`:

I tried this:

```
SELECT
CASE ..condition1..
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END
AS first,
CASE ..condition2..
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END
AS second,
CASE 
    WHEN newTable.first = 0 AND newTable.second = 0 
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END
AS third
INTO newTable
FROM oldTable
```

But I am getting an error:

```
The multi-part identifier "newTable.first" could not be bound;
The multi-part identifier "newTable.second" could not be bound.
```

Could you please suggest me something?

Is there a way to fill third field in this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must repeat the conditions first and third and newtable don't exist yet.

```
SELECT
CASE ..condition1..
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END
AS first,
CASE ..condition2..
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END
AS second,
CASE 
    WHEN ..condition1.. OR ..condition2.. 
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END
AS third
INTO newTable
FROM oldTable
```

Note:

```
newTable.first = 0 AND newTable.second = 0 

= NOT ..condition1.. AND  NOT ..condition2..

= ..condition1.. OR ..condition2.. (by applying de'morgans law)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is your answer

```
select *,CASE WHEN tblTemo.first = 0 AND tblTemo.second = 0  THEN 1  ELSE 0 END from (

SELECT
CASE ..condition1..
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END
AS first,
CASE ..condition2..
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END
AS second
) as tblTemo
INTO newTable
FROM oldTable
```

you can not direct you column alias in your query